# Words in string equal to a permutation of words in another string

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I want to find out if one string is equal to at least one of the permutations of the other string.
For example, the output of the following two comparisons must be `true`:

```
print('united states of America' == 'America united states of')
print('united states of America' == 'states of united America')
```

I used the `itertools.permutations` method to find permutations, but
I want it for words not the sentence nor the letters in the string.

So not `'abcd' == 'bcad'` equals `True`, but `'a b c d' == 'b c a d'`
should be `True`.

Comment: Do you want `'abcd' == 'bcad'` to equal `True`?

Comment: @RoyCohen No, but 'a b c d' == 'b c a d'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need `itertools.permutations`. Instead, compare *reordered* strings, with all words sorted:

```
def reorder_str(s):
    return " ".join(sorted(s.split()))

print(reorder_str('united states of America') == reorder_str('America united states of'))
# True

print(reorder_str('united states of America') == reorder_str('america united states of'))
# False
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
import itertools
def f(s1, s2):
   perms = itertools.permutations(s1.split(" "))
   return tuple(s2.split(" ")) in perms

>>> f('united states of America', 'America united states of')
True
>>> f('united states of America', 'states of united America')
True
>>> f("a b c d", "b a c d")
True
```

Comment: This is horrendously slow, the time complexity is `O(n!)`, tham means that even a relativly small number of words like 10 will take 3628800 calculations.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I would recommend is to find the frequency of each word in each string and compare that.

The actual implementation is a little bit more tricky, we first find the frequencies of each word in the first string, and then for each word in te second string we decrement the frequency by 1, if the frequency is less than 0, we know that the second string has that word more times that the first string and we can skip the rest of the words.

```py
def compare(s1, s2):
    count = {}  # this is the frequencies dict
    for word in s1.split():
        count[word] = count.get(word, 0) + 1  # increment the frequency of the word
    for word in s2.split():
        count[word] = count.get(word, 0) - 1  # decrement the frequency of the word
        if count[word] < 0:
            # s2 has more of this word than s1
            return False
    return True
```

---

This algorithm is faster than sorting or `itertools.permutations` but takes more space. The time complexity of this algorithm is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of words, compared with `O(nlog n)` for sorting, and `O(n!)` for `itertools.permutations`.

Comment: Sweet, nice solution

Answer (score 2):

Just check the words frequencies

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter('united states of America')
c1 = Counter('America united states of')
c2 = Counter('states of united America'

print(c == c1 == c2)
# True
```

Comment: Nice solution! but it should even be enough just to check equality between the counters c, c1 and c2.

Comment: This solution is slower than my solution because it first calculates all the frequencies, and only than start comparing. My solution will short-circuit before calculating all the frequencies.

Comment: @RoyCohen what i would be interested in is how Counter is implemented in Cpython in this case. Could it be possible that Counter would be faster than your answer if more happens under the hood in Cpython?

Comment: @tbjorch In small strings, yes. short-circuiting will on avarage save you from checking half the words in the second string, that can be huge if you're dealing with very long strings. I don't know about any Cython optimisations or if `Counter` is even written in Cython but I bet the time saved is neglecable in long strings. So when dealing with long strings, my solution will, on avarge, be faster.

Comment: @RoyCohen Interesting. I tried now comparing execution time of Counter vs your solution and it breaks even pretty fast. Already around 300 word long strings, using Counter becomes faster. At smaller string sizes, the execution time is so fast that it becomes neglectable for both alternatives, but given larger amounts of text, Counter is outperforming. I suppose this is because of the underlying implementation of Counter. Given that, i would still vote for going with Counter since it's more scalable.

Comment: @tbjorch How did you test this? Or more specifically, how did you generate the words? If you use random words, then the short-curcuitwouldn't be used often, but if you chose a random word from a small list, then the advantages of the short-curcuit will be bigger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229533/discussion-between-roy-cohen-and-tbjorch).

Answer (score 1):

A computationally more efficient way of doing it compared to permutations would be to split and sort the strings and compare the sorted lists. A challenge with generating permutations is that as soon as you start getting just a couple of words, e.g. 10, then you would have 10! number of permutations (3628800) generated which you would compare your string against making it very inefficient very fast.

```py
string_1 = "states of united America"
string_2 = "united states of America"

def check_if_perm(s1, s2):
    return sorted(s1.split()) == sorted(s2.split())
```

outputs:

```
True
```

Comment: What is the time and space complexities of sorting? I'm prety sure the time complexity is `O(nlog n)` but I have no clue about the space complexity.

Comment: Yes i suppose the time complexity would be `O(n log n)`.

Comment: I google'd it and the python sort algorithm will use, worst case, `O(n)` extra space, which is what my solution uses. To be fair this is still better than my solution in terms of space compexity since the space complexity for sorting is worst case, while the space complexity for my solution is prety much fixed (it is proportional to the number of distinct words).

Answer (score -1):

If `itertools.permutations` is not a must, I would use sets:

```
>>> set('united states of America'.split()) == set('America united states of'.split())
True
>>> set('united states of America'.split()) == set('America united states off'.split())
False
```

Comment: This won't work for `'united united America'` and `'united America America'`.

Comment: How about sorting as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/66482236/9441186 then?

Comment: Sorting is slower than my sulotion, check it out.